# Removing classes on one element when class is added to another element via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to toggle classes on repeat (it turns a one second animation on and off every 5 seconds) but I need the repeat to stop when another element gets a class added to it via jQuery.

Been trying jQuery's if() and looking more into event delegation but not sure if that's the right track since this isn't a click event. The separate "trigger" element gets an "active" class when the page is scrolled into that section - this is when I need the animation to stop and not play again.

This is the one second animation that repeats every 5 seconds (I'm using this code in WordPress so using "jQuery" instead of "$")

```
setInterval(function(){ 

   jQuery(".featBrands").toggleClass("animated bounce"); 
   setTimeout(function(){

     jQuery(".featBrands").toggleClass("animated bounce"); 
   },1000);

},5000);
```

This is the code I've been trying to use with no luck. The "active" class is being adding dynamically through the theme when the page is scrolled to this particular section

```
if (jQuery('.featBrands a').hasClass( "active" )) {

  jQuery(".featBrands").removeClass("animated bounce");
}
```

I expected the "animated bounce" to be removed as long as the anchor element inside had "active" added to it. Instead, nothing happens in the DOM as far as the class being removed. I even tried adding a new class called "stop" that would pause all the animations (since it's in CSS), but still no luck.

Comment: Providing a runnable [mcve] would sure help here. Click on `<>` in question editor and you can use the stack snippets to easily include jQuery.js, and enough html and css to run it right here in the page

Comment: What if I included a link to the page in question? The code that adds the "active" class comes from the WordPress theme I'm using so not sure what that code looks like

Comment: Well ideally the question should be self contained. You can copy sample html right from browser dev tools element inspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToggleClass will add and remove class to the selector specified. but in your case you dont want the toggle to take effect if there is an active class added to the anchor element. 
In that case you can check whether the active class exists in the anchor tag and then apply the toggle class.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
if (!jQuery('.featBrands a').hasClass( "active" )) {
jQuery(".featBrands").toggleClass("animated bounce"); 
setTimeout(function(){

 jQuery(".featBrands").toggleClass("animated bounce"); 
 },1000);
}

},5000);
```

Comment: PERFECT!! Thank you so much - that did the trick! Is there a way to stop the animation permanently once the "active" class is added the first time? So the animation only plays on page load and up until the "active" class is added?

Comment: For that you need to move the code inside the setinterval method as a seperate function and then call clearInterval() method when the class "active" has been added. Refer below link for reference,  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp